# How to change android views without user interaction and or app update

Tags: android, facebook, angular, cordova, auto-update

Basically i'm working on android apps using hybrid cross platform frame work (angular- cordova) , I want to update the user screens without their knowledge or without updating app, like for example if we change and supply the screens in the back-end, apps screens should get updated.

Currently we have app update mechanism which we want to replace .

For reference example like Facebook screens get changed with out app update or user knowledge .

same way we want to do , any one please give some solution .
Or if their are better way please suggest me.

Many thanks to all.

Comment: by asking the users at the time of installing your app , to turn on **auto update** of play store always :-D.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get UI from server.in server you need boolean variable like changes true or false if change true then you get UI from server and create a view dynamically.Like you get button from server,server side define button colour style and all property then get response from server in conditional statement like you check a response name is button then you create a  button dynamically with setTag attribute.and you need to store response from database.You use any database like realm,sqlite and check every response all time like changed=true or false if true then you create dynamical UI and remove old database and add new server response to database

Comment: Sir i tried sending html tags as objects from server but no use, because what ever tags i sent from server are not rendering as html . whatever i receive from server are displaying as text mean as it is .If my way of approach is wrong than please tel me right.

Comment: you use android?

Comment: No i use angular-cordova

Comment: i already develop this type of app in android.but i don't know how to use in cordova

Comment: Sir can you share me some references of it so i ll try adopt it.

Comment: give your email id i shear via email

Comment: anjan.bc2@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I am not using but I heard about **Silent Push Notification**, google it about Silent push notification for your framework.
User don't have any knowledge about getting any notification and you can do your work like layout changing

Example

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=silent+push+notification+cordova

Comment: Sir i agree that push notifications do receive the data without user intervention but my problem is i want to update the user screens without their knowledge .Like Facebook updates their UI without app update

Comment: yes, you need to develop both things in your app when you want to update than change the flag by push notification